# edit install4j runtime vmoptions to redirect stderr and stdout

Tags: install4j

We are switching from installanywhere to install4j.  With the former we could just add a specific redirect option to the launcher's config file (lax file) when we needed to do additional debugging (app runs as a service on linux, so by default the launchers swallow stderr and stdout) and redirect stderr/stdout to a file.

Can't find any documentation anywhere on how to edit an install4j vmoptions file for an installed app, in the same way.

Anybody know how to do it ?

(Just to be clear, this is for the app launcher that was generated by install4j to start the service, not for the installer itself.)

Answer (score 0):

install4j does not have such an option, but it's fairly easy to set up redirection in your application conditionally:

```
if (Boolean.getBoolean("debug.redirect")) {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("stdout.log")));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("stderr.log")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that, at least as of version 7, install4j now supports this feature via the Launcher wizard in two different ways:

#### Allow `-console` parameter

On the [Executable info](https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/steps/launcher/wizard/executable.html) page, you can configure a GUI application to support the `-console` parameter:

> If the user supplies the -console parameter when starting the launcher from a console window, the launcher will try to acquire the console window and redirect stdout and stderr to it.

Note that the install4j launcher will not consume the `-console` parameter, and it will be passed on to your application, so you need to be prepared to handle it.

#### Redirect stdout and stderr to files

On the [Executable info > Advanced options > Redirection](https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/steps/launcher/wizard/redirection.html) page, you can specify separate files to which stdout and stderr will be redirected.

Using these options will override the `-console` parameter, if enabled:

> If you redirect stderr and stdout in the redirection settings, that output will not be written to the console.